# How to call a React component function from inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in an event function and I would like to create a new alert popup (I am using the [react-portal](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal/) library):

```
onNewAlert: function(username) {

    var divModal = (
        <Portal ref={'Portal'+username}>
                <div id={'div'+username}>
                    <br /><br/ >Alert for {username}
                </div>
        </Portal>);
    ...
}
```

But then I would have to call a function that is inside a `Portal`. I could normally do this with references if I was in the `render()` function, but I am in an event.

```
    this.refs['Portal'+username].openPortal(); // openPortal is a function of the Portal component
```

Is there a way to call a component function for a component created on the fly in a javascript function?

Comment: Can't you just set `isOpen={true}` on your Portal?

Comment: @Aaron I do not see such property in the [portal.js source code](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal/blob/master/lib/portal.js) but thanks for the idea, I guess I can modify his source code...

Comment: The docs mention `isOpen` but I see `isOpened` in the source code...

Comment: You gave me an idea...I'm trying to code a wrapper over the Portal (kindof PortalFactory) but maybe someone else will have a better idea

Comment: could you please add a minimal complete component that demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could call `portal.openPortal()` it wouldn't do anything since the component created in the event handler wouldn't be attached to the DOM.

Instead of trying to render the Portal in the event handler function, the event handler should change the component state which will trigger `render()`.

```
onNewAlert: function(username) {
    this.setState({ showAlert: true });
}
```

The `render()` function would then use the state variable for the `Portal` component's `isOpened` property:

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <Portal isOpened={this.state.showAlert}>
                ...
            </Portal>
        </div>
    );
}
```